# Can't clone TFS Git Repository using Team Explorer

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

i can't clone TFS Git Repository to Eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0) using Team Explorer Everywhere.
Error occurred when trying

```
Error cloning the **Project Name** repository.
**url clone**: not authorized
```

I checked the permissions of the repository, and I seem to see that I have read permission.

What permissions should I have specifically?

I also tried to import it through File -> Import -> Projects from Team Foundation Server but the project is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What permissions should I have specifically?

In TFS(Azure DevOps Server)  Individual repositories inherit permissions from the top-level Git Repositories entry. Branches inherit a subset of permissions from assignments made at the repository level. For branch permissions and policies, see Set branch permissions and Improve code quality with branch policies.

[image]

With Readers permission, you should be able to clone the Git repo. However, a
ccording to TFS permission setting, most groups and **almost all permissions**, **Deny trumps Allow**. If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to **Deny**, that user will **not be able** to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to **Allow**.

Please double check if you are deny in some other group (as a member of) which may cause this issue.

---

A way to narrow down your issue related to permission or any other things such as Team Explorer.  **You could use git command line instead, try to directly git clone files from TFS repo by using git command line.** See if this works in your side.

Comment: @ PatrickLu-MSFT thanks for the reply.
I use Microsoft Team Foundation Server directly from a local installation (http: // {server}: {port} / tfs), how can I see the permissions and policies of the branch?
I seem to belong to the TFS Collaborators Group, so you should be able to clone the Git repository. How can I see all the groups I belong to?

Also, how can I test a file for clone files from the repository?

I'm a beginner with TFS.

Ps: this is a security screen for all GIT repositories (https://ibb.co/B2FJtx0)

Comment: @BenitoToscano If you want to see the permissions and policies of the branch. Please follow this tutorial here：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops **To narrow down if your issue related to user's permission**. Suggest first use git command from git bash to clone the repo first. Besides, according to your shared screenshot, looks you belongs to contributor group, which is able to clone Git repo. This is for all git reposistroy, you could click that repo to check for a specific repo.

Comment: As suggested, I tried to git the clone files directly from the TFS repository using git command line (git clone {url-clone}) and the clone happened successfully. So let me have them. Do you ever fail from Eclipse with Team Explorer?

Comment: @BenitoToscano Yes, I have also got some issue when using eclipse to direct perform Git operations with TFS. Not sure if your issue is the same with "Eclipse’s EGit is built on JGit, and unfortunately, recent versions of JGit actively reject NTLM authentication, resulting in “Authentication not supported” when connecting to on-premises installations of TFS that require NTLM. " Take a look at the last question in this link here: https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere#frequently-asked-questions-faq